# tint imageview affected by darkmode android

Tags: android, imageview

I had a little issue with an imageview using a tint, the default color of my file `arrow_filled` is **Black**, and it doesn't change the color to **white**.

```
 <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ccp"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_filled"
                app:tint="@color/white" />
```

I use this theme :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
```

Comment: You can try to set the color inside the drawable file itself.

Comment: no, I can't, it's a png file

Comment: Change PNG file to SVG :p

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `AppCompatImageView` instead

```
<AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ccp"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_filled"
            app:tint="@color/white" />
```